# How to test REST API request (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `REST API`, for example: I already create REST users, for creating user end point is go to "localhost:3000/users" POST method.

So pattern of param should be like this :

```
:user => {:name => "apple", :address => "heaven"}
```

My question is :

How to create pattern above, then I test it to endpoint POST method ?

I already test with `postman` client, but failed because my pattern incorrect (miss `root : user`)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller test will catch the type of error you're describing, and is more efficient than an end-to-end test. Example in RSpec:

```
it 'creates a new user' do
  post :create, user: {name: 'apple', address: 'heaven'}, format: 'json'

  assert_response :success
  expect(response).to render_template(:create)
  expect(assigns(:user).name).to eq('apple')
  expect(assigns(:user).address).to eq('heaven')
end
```

I have used `curl` (in code) to test APIs end-to-end. The [Faraday gem](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) would probably work as well.

With the `curl` request, you'll need to pass the `-X POST` parameter and a `-d` parameter for the data. `-d` can have the following formats:

```
-d "user[name]=apple" -d "user[address]=heaven"
-d {"user": {"name": "apple", "address": "heaven"}}
```

You can also pass headers with `-H`.

Altogether:

`curl http://your_url -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d {"user": {"name": "apple", "address": "heaven"}}`